# Use a virtual async Task declared in C# and override it in F#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, f#, async-await

Currently I have a piece of code written in C# that is being consumed by a piece of F# code both being .NET libraries. Here is the issue:

Assume I have the following class in the C# library:

```
namespace Jaxrtech.Logic
{
    public class Initializer
    {
        public Initializer()
        {
        }

        public async Task Setup()
        {
            // Run implementation independed setup here

            // Now call the implementation specific override
            await OnSetup();

            // Do any additional setup after the implemntation specific stuff
        }

        // Allow for custom setup tasks to be ran by the Initializer
        protected virtual async Task OnSetup()
        {
            // Return a completed task by default
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

And is then overridden in F# as such:

```
open System.Threading.Tasks
open Jaxrtech.Logic

type CustomInitializer() =
    inherit Initializer()

    ...

    override this.OnSetup(): Task = async {
        // custom async logic here
        // ex:
        do! updateTables()
        do! validateData()
    }

    (* Error: This expression was expected to have type
                Task
              but here has type
                Async<'a>' *)
```

The issue is the `this.OnSetup()` member is trying to return `Async<unit>` but the C# library is expecting a normal empty `Task`. I've tried looking through the [MSDN `Control.Async` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370232.aspx)  but did not find much of any avail. `Async.StartAsTask` still returns a typed task, i.e. `Task<'a>`. So something like this does not seem to solve the problem:

```
override this.OnSetup(): Task =
    let f: Async<unit> = async {
        // Implementation specific setup code here
    }
    Async.StartAsTask f
```

Instead now you will be greeted by a similar error message:

```
This expression was expected to have type  
  Task  
but here has type  
  Task<'a>'
```

You may then ask why I am not using events in the first place. The main reason for that is then since you are going to be returning `async void` there is no way to properly use `await` on the event to complete.

Finally, I luckily have control over both the C# and F# libraries. Any reasonable way to override this `protected virtual async Task` function or alike would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This article demonstrates how to convert to plain `Task`: http://theburningmonk.com/2012/10/f-helper-functions-to-convert-between-asyncunit-and-task/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that `Task<'a>` derives from `Task` you can just slightly modify your last snippet

```
override this.OnSetup(): Task =
    let f: Async<unit> = async {
    // Implementation specific setup code here
    }
    upcast Async.StartAsTask f
```

Comment: I don't have a F# compiler in-front of me at the moment, but looking at [MSDN, Task<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx) does in fact inherit from the non-generic Task class. Thanks for the insight @desco I'll just have to check for any additional issues when I get the chance but it looks like it should surely work.